Ubuntu 24.04 not booting after upgrading it
I have 24.04 but then i upgraded it using

sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

. But then after the upgrade it lost wireless Internet connection right away then i decided to restart the machine to my surprise ut couldn't boot back thi
s is not tye second time it's happening it's heading straight to memory check at it can take days in that page just checking tyee memory and no errors being found. So a tried using command line tyej inwas told that kernel missing what what something like that

Generally, use a liveboot usb or cd, then chroot into your installation, update, upgrade, make sure you have a kernel installed (uname -a). In your case you probably just need to complete your upgrade, I added install -f below.
If you not getting any boot options, you will need to reinstall grub (grub-install /dev/sdX) where x is drive you want to install it on.
See Update Failure
Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.

Press Ctrl-Alt-F1

    sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt

    sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev

    sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc

    sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

    sudo chroot /mnt

    apt update

    apt install -f

    apt upgrade

